# Insert multiple documents in mongodb collection with a single insert statement using php

Tags: php, mongodb

In PHP I have some data to insert. The sample data is shown below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [uuid] => membership-60f929a1989d6960400020
            [channel] => channel-594b9e3568ac3969784876
            [user] => user-5b1e6e1b636e5325325732
            [emailnotifications] => off
            [email] => demo@xyz.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uuid] => membership-60f929a198a1a549293025
            [channel] => channel-594b9edcdea14894901526
            [user] => user-5b1e6e1b636e5325325732
            [emailnotifications] => off
            [email] => demo@xyz.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uuid] => membership-60f929a198a2b975658255
            [channel] => channel-5ab261a60fe87688298186
            [user] => user-5b1e6e1b636e5325325732
            [emailnotifications] => off
            [email] => demo@vizsafe.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uuid] => membership-60f929a198a3b292013762
            [channel] => channel-5e668d5522526659309093
            [user] => user-5b1e6e1b636e5325325732
            [emailnotifications] => off
            [email] => demo@vizsafe.com
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [uuid] => membership-60f929a198a4a688473796
            [channel] => channel-5e668d6fafbbe937126299
            [user] => user-5b1e6e1b636e5325325732
            [emailnotifications] => off
            [email] => demo@vizsafe.com
        )    
   

)
```

I would like to insert each element of the array as single document. For example :-

```
Array (
                [uuid] => membership-60f929a1989d6960400020
                [channel] => channel-594b9e3568ac3969784876
                [user] => user-5b1e6e1b636e5325325732
                [emailnotifications] => off
                [email] => demo@xyz.com
       )
```

should be inserted as a separate document . This should be achieved using a single insert statement . Also the version of mongodb being used is 2.4 so I cannot use insertMany. Can this be done ? Any leads would be helpful. Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: Considering it's quite old version of mongod, please provide details of the php driver. v2.4 is not even listed on the driver compatibility matrix https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/

Comment: I am using php version 5.5.35

Comment: php driver is the mongodb extension you added to be able to connect to mongo 2.4 from php 5.5. I asked about the version of the extension. You can find it in phpinfo().

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.3/tutorial/crud/#insert-many-documents

Comment: I cannot use inserMany with Mongo version 2.4 .I have mentioned this in the question. This has been introduced in version 3.2https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/

Comment: What's the error? IIRC 2.4 was the first version to accept multiple document in the insert().

Comment: Can I chat with you? All the arrays get inserted in one document and not in separate documents. I am able to insert multiple documents in mongo shell but not from php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235178/discussion-between-alex-blex-and-webdev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**

It's not possible for v2.4.

The batch insert [was added to the PHP mongo driver in v1.5.0](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver-legacy/releases/tag/1.5.0) combined with the switch to [mongodb v2.6 write protocol](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/2.6/#new-write-operation-protocol):

> It supports all new features for MongoDB 2.6, including:
>
> - Aggregate can now return a cursor
> - Aggregation pipelines can now be explained
> - Possible to set maxTimeMS for commands and queries
> - Transparent support for the new command-based MongoDB write API
> - **New MongoWriteBatch classes (using the new MongoDB write API)**

---

Previous answer:

The question is about legacy driver https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo/1.5.1

You need to use MongoInsertBatch to insert multiple documents.

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoinsertbatch.php (doesn't exist any more):

```
$docs = array();
$docs[] = array("my" => "demo");
$docs[] = array("is" => "working");
$docs[] = array("pretty" => "well");

$batch = new MongoInsertBatch($collection);
foreach($docs as $document) {
    $batch->add($document);
}
$retval = $batch->execute(array("w" => 1));
```

In your case `$collection` is `$this->db->memberships`

As a side note, you really need to upgrade the stack. It's a decade old.

Comment: For now , I should upgrade the driver to which version?

Comment: Sorry, it's the whole stack I'm afraid. Mongo v.2.4 reached end of life in 2016, the php driver is officially "maintained" but there were no single patch since 2017, php v5.6 was decommissioned in 2019.

Comment: The latest stable Mongo is v5.0, php 8.0 and driver ext 1.10 + lib 1.9. Unfortunately all 3 components are not quite compatible, and the driver is the most affected. It's literally a product which has nothing in common with the legacy driver. Basically you will need to rewrite most of the code.

Comment: If these three are not compatible, then which is the best combination?

Comment: I was probably not clear enough. the latest stable is the best combination. It's the latest versions of each component is not compatible with yours. The major version upgrade implies BC break even with consecutive versions. You can check release notes for Mongo and PHP to see what has dropped. The driver is completely different.

Comment: The code above will through a Mongoprotocol exception with Mongo 2.4. It will not work with versions lower than Mongo 2.6

Comment: Fair enough. I updated the answer with explanations. It's exactly why they have compatibility matrix in the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/php/#mongodb-compatibility  There was a similar one for the legacy driver and it included mongo versions < 2.6  but it was removed long time ago.